# Is it Possible for a Java Applet to Record Cursor Movements Inside the Applet?

Tags: web-browser, java, user-tracking

I am using my mouse to interact with a Java applet in a browser. Clearly the party that owns the Java applet can record where I click inside the applet. What I'm wondering about now is whether it is possible for that party to also record the movements of my cursor (i.e. the paths I take when I move my cursor around) within the Java Applet. Is this possible?

I know that it is possible to track user mouse movements within the browser window using JavaScript.

Comment: What does this has to do with security?

Comment: @Sky For certain reasons, I am looking to avoid having my cursor movements within the applet tracked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to track mouse movements with Java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html

Or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321877/tracking-mouse-movement-in-java

Or

http://mrbool.com/creating-a-simple-mouse-analyzer-with-java-swing/24507